# Recompiling Ubuntu stock kernel

Tags: 11.10, kernel, compiling

I want to recompile the stock Ubuntu kernel (on Oneiric) with just one change: include usbcore as a kernel module so it can be reloaded at runtime (I have some issue with usb support crashing at certain times and want to avoid rebooting).

I am following [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/installation-guide/ia64/kernel-baking.html) instructions. I had/have two issues:

1. I have already found out from the docs of kernel-package, that instead of what above instructions suggest, I should apparently be using the `--append-to-version` flag of `make-kpkg` to give a custom name for my compiled kernel (instead of just `--revision`).
2. As I said I want to start of with all the default settings like in the Ubuntu stock kernel. When I start from the sources in the ubuntu package `linux-source-3.0.0` and just call `make menuconfig`, will I be presented with the Ubuntu stock configuration, or some other defaults (mainline?). Should I then be rather copying a default configuration from somewhere else (e.g. `/boot/config-...`)?

Cheers,

Nikolaus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I just gave somebody this answer an hour ago or so I'd hope you'd get a stock configuration.

Reasoning:
When you download the source via `apt-get source linux-image-3.0.0-16-generic` or whatever it downloads the original Debian source then Ubuntu patches and applies them. Theoretically that'd include a .config...

Comment: Just doubled checked and I was correct in my assumptions. It doesn't include a .config, but it does include Ubuntu presets somewhere. For example, the "arbitrary version signature" is Ubuntu 3.0.0-15.26-generic

Comment: I double checked as well. When you run "make menuconfig" once, but dont change anything, it will create a .config that is identical to /boot/config-3.0.0-16-generic. Thanks for the response.